# Cannot be resolved to a type (infinite error until stackoverflow)

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, netbeans

I am getting these errors in Tomcat log out (in Netbeans). Althought web application is running fine in browser.

```
An error occurred at line: 7 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp
LoginModel cannot be resolved to a type
4:     <!--header start here -->
5:     <%
6:         LoginModel loginModel;
7:         loginModel = (LoginModel) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("loginModel");
8:     %>
9:     <div>
10:         <div class="alignright lgouter">
```

In my webapplication I am no where including header.jsp but how to trace why its calling header.jsp and where?

class is located at: `com.mycomp.mct.domain.LoginModel`
but error is `Only a type can be imported. com.mycomp.domain.LoginModel resolves to a package`

why its searching without `.mct.` in package?

here is how I am including

```
<%@page import="com.mycomp.mct.domain.LoginModel"%>
<div class="header" >
```

Comment: Is it precompiling your jsps?

Comment: Did you import all the required classes?
    <%@ page import="my.package.LoginModel" %>

Comment: how to check is it pre commpiling?

Comment: If it is imported it cannot be resolved for some reason. Where is the class of LoginModel located?

Comment: I'm asking because error 'LoginModel cannot be resolved to a type' suggests that there is a problem with class visibility.

Comment: Please show the line in .jsp file where you import your class.

Comment: Is this class properly located within WEB-INF?

Comment: Showing physical path to LoginModel.java file would be helpful. I would take a look at package declaration in your java file as well.

Comment: D:\MACDTV1.00\src\com\smartlead\mct\domain\LoginModel.java